# Объединить две несвязанные таблицы

Tags: mysql

Есть два запроса

```
`SELECT 
  order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method method,
  sum(case `order`.order_status when 'paid' then 1 else 0 end) paid,
  sum(case `order`.order_status when 'later' then 1 else 0 end) later
FROM order_customFields 
  INNER JOIN `order` ON order_customFields.order_id = `order`.order_id
WHERE
  order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date >= date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day), interval 1 month) and
      order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date < date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day) 
AND order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method is not null
GROUP BY    
   order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method `
```

Второй запрос

```
`SELECT 
total,from_sale,from_sent,on_sent
FROM deliverability.delivery_count_repo
where add_time >= CURDATE()`
```

Результат первого - вывод 3 колонок, результат второго вывод 5 колонок. Как можно объединить их в один, чтобы на выходе было 8 колонок?

Comment: _результат второго вывод 5 колонок._ Я насчитал только 4... _Как можно объединить их в один, чтобы на выходе было 8 колонок?_ Да никак, пока не появится вменяемый критерий соответствия записей первого и второго наборов, причём строго 1:1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объединить, конечно, можно. Только без связи между таблицами у Вас получится мешанина.
А также кол-во записей будет `Count(table1) * Count(table2)`.

Вам нужно просто сделать конструкцию типа `SELECT * FROM table1, table2`.

Что-то типа такого:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM 
(SELECT 
  order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method method,
  sum(case `order`.order_status when 'paid' then 1 else 0 end) paid,
  sum(case `order`.order_status when 'later' then 1 else 0 end) later
FROM order_customFields 
  INNER JOIN `order` ON order_customFields.order_id = `order`.order_id
WHERE
  order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date >= date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day), interval 1 month) and
      order_customFields.order_customFields_order_date < date_sub(curdate(), interval day(curdate()) - 1 day) 
AND order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method is not null
GROUP BY    
   order_customFields.order_customFields_delivery_method) t1,
(SELECT 
total,from_sale,from_sent,on_sent
FROM deliverability.delivery_count_repo
where add_time >= CURDATE()) t2
```

Ну т.е., грубо говоря, каждый запрос заключаете в подзапрос, запятую между ними, и "выбрать все".

`t1.*, t2.*` можно смело заменить просто на `*`